# Understand sar command output Unix

Tags: linux, sar

I am trying to analyze my server CPU utilization and processing time .So for that i have taken sar output for the reference.But i am not able to understand it properly i help to understand the output so that i can identify the utilization and processing time.Below is the sample output :

```
 12:00:01 AM     CPU      %usr     %nice      %sys   %iowait    %steal      %irq     %soft    %guest     %idle
12:01:01 AM     all     77.57      0.01      1.07      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.59      0.00     20.75
12:01:01 AM       0     92.88      0.00      0.70      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.15      0.00      6.27
12:01:01 AM       1     88.18      0.02      2.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.80      0.00      9.00
12:01:01 AM       2     92.71      0.00      0.68      0.00      0.00      0.00      1.12      0.00      5.49
12:01:01 AM       3     86.55      0.00      2.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.68      0.00     10.76
12:01:01 AM       4     92.89      0.00      0.65      0.00      0.00      0.00      1.13      0.00      5.32
12:01:01 AM       5     82.82      0.00      1.77      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.65      0.00     14.75
12:01:01 AM       6     91.21      0.03      0.73      0.00      0.00      0.00      1.20      0.00      6.82
12:01:01 AM       7     79.84      0.00      1.55      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.60      0.00     18.00
12:01:01 AM       8     91.15      0.00      0.67      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.12      0.00      8.07
12:01:01 AM       9     74.75      0.00      1.62      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.54      0.00     23.09
12:01:01 AM      10     90.86      0.02      0.70      0.02      0.00      0.00      0.12      0.00      8.29
12:01:01 AM      11     70.92      0.00      1.30      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.47      0.00     27.31
12:01:01 AM      12     91.02      0.00      0.72      0.00      0.00      0.00      1.23      0.00      7.03
12:01:01 AM      13     68.63      0.02      1.40      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.45      0.00     29.50
12:01:01 AM      14     91.14      0.00      0.62      0.00      0.00      0.00      1.30      0.00      6.94
12:01:01 AM      15     66.32      0.00      1.40      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.38      0.00     31.90
12:01:01 AM      16     90.15      0.00      0.63      0.00      0.00      0.00      1.25      0.00      7.96
12:01:01 AM      17     61.44      0.02      1.34      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.48      0.00     36.69
12:01:01 AM      18     88.00      0.00      0.68      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.17      0.00     11.15
12:01:01 AM      19     58.43      0.00      1.41      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.47      0.00     39.70
12:01:01 AM      20     87.17      0.00      0.68      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.15      0.00     11.99
12:01:01 AM      21     55.45      0.00      1.37      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.50      0.00     42.68
12:01:01 AM      22     86.34      0.00      0.65      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.15      0.00     12.86
```

In CPU what does all means and please if somebody can help me to understand the complete output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Understanding the output of SAR command

%user: This shows the total time that the processor is spending on different user processes

%sys: this shows the percentage of time spend by the processor for operating system tasks(because the previous user shows the time spend for user end process)

%iowait: the name iowait itself suggests that its the time spend by processor waiting for devices(input and output)

%nice: Most of you guys must be knowing that a user can change the priority of a process in linux by changing the nice value in Linux. This table shows the time spend by CPU for process whose nice value has been changed.

%steal:  This column shows the amount to time spend by a CPU (which is virtualized), for resources from the physical CPU

%idle: This suggests the idle time spend by the processor.

There are plenty of (other) examples and descriptions out there, just need to search it up.
In the CPU column 'all' means that the line contains the average stats for all CPUs (cores/threads).

Comment: in cpu what does all means

Comment: it means that the stat of all CPU's are in that line. what parameters did you use to get this output ?

Comment: sar -P ALL will display for you the statistics /core(thread) also, and the all line will contain the average of all cores/threads